# Issue in Leach Protocol Installation : invalid command name "Resource/Energy"

Tags: macos, ns2

I tried to install leach protocol in ns2 version 2.35 by following the steps in this link :
http://www.nsnam.com/2015/05/leach-p...in-ns2-ns.html

After completing all the steps in the link, i tried to execute the leach_test, but it shows some errors in the leach.err file :

```
invalid command name "Resource/Energy"
    while executing
"Resource/Energy instproc setParams {args} {
    $self instvar energyLevel_ alarmLevel_
    set energyLevel_ [lindex $args 0]
    set alarmLevel_ [lind..."
    (file "/Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/mit/rca/resources/ns-energy-resource.tcl" line 11)
    invoked from within
"source.orig /Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/mit/rca/resources/ns-energy-resource.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]"
    invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]
..."
    (procedure "source" line 8)
    invoked from within
"source /Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/mit/rca/resources/ns-energy-resource.tcl"
    (file "mit/uAMPS/sims/uamps.tcl" line 18)
    invoked from within
"source.orig mit/uAMPS/sims/uamps.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]"
    invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]
..."
    (procedure "source" line 8)
    invoked from within
"source mit/uAMPS/sims/uamps.tcl"
    (file "/Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/mobility/leach.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source.orig /Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/mobility/leach.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]"
    invoked from within
"if [$instance_ is_http_url $fileName] {
set buffer [$instance_ read_url $fileName]
uplevel eval $buffer
} else {
uplevel source.orig[list $fileName]
..."
    (procedure "source" line 8)
    invoked from within
"source /Users/houcine/Documents/ns2/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/mobility/$opt(rp).tcl"
    (file "tcl/ex/wireless.tcl" line 187)
```

I have made a lot of research about the solution of the problem but i didn't find anything.

Any help about this issue please ?

Thank you very much.

System : MAC OS X 10.11 El Capitain

NS 2 Version : ns 2.35

NB : The installation in MAC OSX is almost like the one on Ubuntu. The only changes is the home path.

Answer (score 0):

Re http://www.nsnam.com/2015/05/leach-p...in-ns2-ns.html

The above "pradeepkumar files" are discussed here, post #11 (and post #7)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/issue-in-leach-protocol-installation-invalid-command-name-resource-energy-4175556129/#11

... And a usable awk script is attached to post #9.

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience to install ns-2.35 and leach in Ubuntu 14.04.

I was trying to install ns-2.35 first and then leach in Ubuntu 14.04. After all configuration was done, I tried to run `leach_test` but the error is shown. When I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX9fooieASE) tutorial, I knew my wrong step. In this tutorial, it shows the `./install` is ran after configure between ns-2.35 and leach is done.

So, I try `./install` again in terminal `~/ns-allinone-2.35`.
When I try `leach_test` again in ns-2.35 the simulation work well.